# Submit form wizard at step

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am stuck on the functionality on submission of each step on next. Every step has its own database table in which it will be stored. I am trying to post each step data into the database while clicking on the 'next' button. It gets submit on the 'Finish' button, but not on each step.

I have tried to submit while using own personal button of each step which is save, it posts data, but after posting I am not able to figure out how to get it back on the form next step.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <form id="wizard_with_validation" method="POST" action="TestPage.php">
    <h3>Account Information</h3>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group form-float">
        <div class="form-line">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" required>
          <label class="form-label">Username*</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-float">
        <div class="form-line">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" required>
          <label class="form-label">Password*</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" name="AccountInfoSubmit" id="AccountInfoSubmit" value="SAVE" class="btn bg-teal waves-effect">
<i class="material-icons">save</i>
<span>SAVE</span>
</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <h3>Contact Information</h3>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group form-float">
        <div class="form-line">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tel" required>
          <label class="form-label">Telephone*</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-float">
        <div class="form-line">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Email" id="email" required>
          <label class="form-label">Email*</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="submit" name="ContactInfoSubmit" value="SAVE" class="btn bg-teal waves-effect">
</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
```

```js
var form = $('#wizard_with_validation').show();
form.steps({
  headerTag: 'h3',
  bodyTag: 'fieldset',
  transitionEffect: 'slideLeft',
  onInit: function(event, currentIndex) {
    $.AdminBSB.input.activate();

    //Set tab width
    var $tab = $(event.currentTarget).find('ul[role="tablist"] li');
    var tabCount = $tab.length;
    $tab.css('width', (100 / tabCount) + '%');

    //set button waves effect
    setButtonWavesEffect(event);
  },
  onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
    if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
      return true;
    }

    if (currentIndex < newIndex) {
      form.find('.body:eq(' + newIndex + ') label.error').remove();
      form.find('.body:eq(' + newIndex + ') .error').removeClass('error');
    }

    form.validate().settings.ignore = ':disabled,:hidden';
    return form.valid();
  },
  onStepChanged: function(event, currentIndex, priorIndex) {
    $('#AccountInfoSubmit').click();
    setButtonWavesEffect(event);
  },
  onFinishing: function(event, currentIndex) {
    form.validate().settings.ignore = ':disabled';

    return form.valid();
  },
  onFinished: function(event, currentIndex) {
    $('#wizard_with_validation').submit();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to submit while using own personal button of each step which is save, it posts data, but after posting I am not able to figure out how to get it back on the form next step.

The server could return the current step's index. This way you would know which next step you would need to render.

Comment: Can you please reference source code for further demonstration?